# unable to call glCreate* in pyOpenGL

Tags: opengl, pyopengl

I'm running a code using pyopengl and have some problems of calling `glCreate*` functions.

The code is running in ubuntu 16.04, python2.7 and the pyopengl version is  PyOpenGL 3.1.3b2 and PyOpenGL-accelerate 3.1.3b2 (already the latest versions).

It has the flowing problems:
when I try to call

> >>> glCreateTextures
>
> OpenGL.platform.baseplatform.glCreateTextures object at 0x7f16de11a050

It seems that the updated version of pyopengl does add this function (or class) but it's creepy that if I try to give it values for initializing:

> >>> glCreateTextures(None,None,None)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in
> File "/media/sinnis/ADDDISK/pyopengl/OpenGL/latebind.py", line 41, in call
> return self._finalCall( *args, **named )
> File "/media/sinnis/ADDDISK/pyopengl/OpenGL/wrapper.py", line 689, in wrapperCall
> result = wrappedOperation( *cArguments )
> File "/media/sinnis/ADDDISK/pyopengl/OpenGL/platform/baseplatform.py", line 414, in call
> self.name, self.name,
> OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glCreateTextures, check for bool(glCreateTextures) before calling

It seems that the it is checking and considering this call an undefined function. That's how it raises problem in the script texture.py and I find that any glCreate* calls has this problem.

Still no solution to fix this problem. Help!

Comment: As far as I know there is no [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) solution for this. You've to use [`glGenTextures`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glGenTextures.html) and [`glBindTexture`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glBindTexture.html). e.g. `texture = glGenTextures(1)` `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)`

Comment: glCreateTextures needs OpenGL context version 4.5.

Comment: The pyopengl 3.1.3 has incorporated functions of OpenGL context version 4.5.